# SSD APFS Corruption

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, apfs, fsck

I'm using a Mac Book Pro mid 2012 running 10.15.7on Samsung EVO 1TB internally.
It was not possible to boot the computer last Friday. I tried to boot in recovery mode, the SSD was not identified as a bootable device.
I removed the SSD and tried to boot it using a UGreen IDE Docking Station without sucess.
Now I have connected the UGreen Docking Station to another Mac computer, fsck_apfs -fy gives the result that there are many invalid checksums, therefore the space manager is invalid,
the whole issue is here:
[fsck_apfs](https://pastebin.com/cxgfRwmz)
Disk utility gives the same output.
I run others tools like Drat/APFS Inspect, the output is the following:

[Drat - APFS Inspect](https://pastebin.com/UyzcfXai)

As you can see there are a lot of checksum validation errors. APFS Inspect says an Ephemeral object is malformed.
Is there any way to fix this checksum error and get the SSD bootable again? Or is the only possible solution to format the entire SSD and reinstall the operating system?
I don't have any idea about the origin of this error and I couldn't find any information about it.
It would be nice to receive some help.

Comment: Not sure if this is the case here, but the sata cable on MBP mid 2012 is a frequent case of failure. You can try to reset the ssd but if the problem starts again, I advise you to replace this sata cable.

Comment: Yes, the simplest fix is to wipe and start over. You have a backup, of course. The cause could still be the SATA cable, as @Jean_JD suggests, even though it wouldn't boot as an external.

Comment: @Jean_JD Yes, I know the issues related to the SATA cable, I changed it 1 year ago and now have a replacement here.I didn't have any problems with the SSD before, so I'm asking to find out the possible cause of the problem. I have a backup, I'll only lose some data

Comment: The best way to protect your data is to turn on Time Machine automatic backup. ; -}